# How do I set a numpy array element to a string of more than one character?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, chr

For example, in the following code, when I attempt to set the element of the array to the concatenated string of `chr((r+97)) + str(c+1)`, it only sets the element to the first digit of the string. How can I fix this?

```
row =   3
col =   3  
sboard = np.empty((row,col),dtype=str)
val = chr((r+97)) + str(c+1)
print(val)
sboard[r,c] = val            
print(sboard)
```

This code outputs

```
[['' '' '']
 ['' '' '']
 ['' '' 'c']]
```

rather than

```
[['' '' '']
 ['' '' '']
 ['' '' 'c3']]
```

Much appreciated, thanks

Comment: replace `str` with 'U2', 2 character unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `chararray`.

Replace:

```
 sboard = np.empty((row,col),dtype=str)
```

With

```
 sboard = np.chararray([3,3],2) # This assumes all of your strings with be 2 characters.
 sboard[:] = ''
```

Comment: Additional information: Numpy is really designed with numerical data in mind. You might want to consider if it is really the best tool for the job with textual analyses.

Comment: P.S. Got the note, but saw you are new. If the answer solved your problem, it's a good idea to accept it so the answerer can get credit (you get some reputation as well).

Comment: I am mostly using it for numerical analysis, but as this is a one off text display, I didn't want to use additional libraries - thank you for the information!